# BASH: DBCA: command not found

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux

When I use `dbca` command as Oracle 11g user I have the following error message:

```
BASH: DBCA:  command not found
```

and when I checked the bash profile I found the following:

```
    # .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

# Oracle Settings
TMP=/tmp; export TMP
TMPDIR=$TMP; export TMPDIR

ORACLE_HOSTNAME=oracledev-srv.etqint.com; export ORACLE_HOSTNAME
#ORACLE_UNQNAME=DB11G; export ORACLE_UNQNAME
#ORACLE_BASE=/oracle11gr2/u01/app/oracle; export ORACLE_BASE
#ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/db_1; export ORACLE_HOME
#ORACLE_SID=DB11G; export ORACLE_SID
PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH; export PATH
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH; export PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib; export CLASSPATH


PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
unset USERNAME
cd $ORACLE_BASE
export PATH
```

Server information: RedHat Linux 6.3, Oracle installed on the server 11g R2 and 12c.

What I did for investigation:

1. check the bash file and found out they are correct
2. navigate to bin file and hit `dbca` but still the same error message
3. edit the bash file manually in-case I missed something
4. reboot the server

And still the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

```
BASH: DBCA:  command not found
```

`DBCA` should be lower-case.

Comment: I always run dbca in lower-case but it show like the on in the title

Answer (score 0):

DBCA can be invoked with `dbca` (lower case).

> check the bash file and found out they are correct

No they are not. The line that defines `ORACLE_HOME` is commented out, this also makes `PATH` incomplete.

> navigate to bin file and hit dbca but still the same error message

If you navigate to the $ORACLE_HOME/bin directory while not having it in `PATH`, use `./dbca` instead of `dbca`

Comment: in-fact even after remove or add # the problem still exist. as well as ./dbca is not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment variable
i.e

```
. oraenv
```

Set the `SID` variable to your SID you already have in your `.bash_profile` script and `$ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1`

Then run `dbca` or `dbca &`